# Есть ли слово "научается"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно брала интервью у одного врача, так вот, он часто использовал слово "научается" ("ребенок научается чему-то"). Именно в виде уже совершенного в прошлом действия - то есть, словом "учится" тут не заменить. А есть ли вообще слово "научается"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть такое слово. Правда, словари дают его с пометой либо устаревшее, либо разговорное. Но есть ли в современном языке другое слово с именно таким значением? Учится - не то. Учится-то учится, но вот научится ли? А научается - это как обещание обязательного результата. Мне кажется, рано его записали в категорию устаревших..

Answer (score 0):

В этом слове — *научается* — оценка степени самостоятельности учащегося, и его стремление научиться. Когда же обучаемый ещё и ребёнок, то одним этим словом выражается уважение как воспитателю и к другому участнику процесса — его учителю. Устойчивое желание учиться идёт от тёплого отношения к носителю знания. Через другую, авторитетную, персону человек научается любить что-то в этой жизни.

Answer (score -2):

Выучивается. Но лучше сделайте над собой усилие, и научитесь говорить "научается".

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Ребус, кроссворд.